# How to retrieve the first email in outlook if keyword exists in the email body using python?

Tags: python, email, parsing, outlook, mapi

Would appreciate any help on how I can export the email body of the first email that pops out into a excel file if a certain keyword exists in the email body using python.

I have managed to access the sub folder so far, below is my code.

```
import win32com.client
outlook=win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mapi=outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
for account in mapi.Accounts:
    #Passing in the account name
    print(account.DeliveryStore.DisplayName)
    
inbox=mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders['Email']
messages=inbox.Items
received_dt=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=10)
received_dt=received_dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')
messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + received_dt + "'")
message=messages.GetLast()
body_content=message.body
print(body_content)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Items.Sort` requires at least one argument (string) - the name of the property to sort on (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.sort). You can then use `Items.Find()` to search on the `PR_BODY` MAPI property:

```
messages=messages.sort('ReceivedTime', true)
message=messages.Find('@SQL="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1000001F" LIKE \'%Test%\' ')
```

Comment: Hello Dmitry, thank you for your answer. Do you know how I can do a search for a keyword in the email body though? As the answers that you have provided will only retrieve the first email in the folder, which is not i wanted.

Comment: See the updated answer above

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use the `Restrict` method and then call the `GetLast` one. So, the following code could re-written using the `Find` method:

```
messages=inbox.Items
received_dt=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=10)
received_dt=received_dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')
messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + received_dt + "'")
```

First, you need to add additional condition to the search string (VBA):

```
messages=inbox.Items
messages.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", False
'Create DASL query for Body using content indexing phrase match for 'office' 
 filter = "@SQL=" + "\""
            + "urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription" + "\""
            + " like '%office%'";
firstMessage = messages.Find(filter)
```

You may find the [Search for a phrase in the body of items in a folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-search-for-a-phrase-in-the-body-of-items-in-a-folder) article helpful.